# Ordenar relação "Many To Many" usando como base campo de outra tabela

Tags: laravel-4, laravel

Estou fazendo uma loja virtual, para conhecer melhor o framework Laravel, e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma tabela chamada products para armazenar as informações relacionadas aos produtos. Possuo também uma tabela chamada types para armazenar os tipos de produtos. Possuo também uma tabela chamada prices, para armazenar os preços dos produtos - separei os preços para poder ter um histórico da alteração de preços dos produtos.

Existem três tipos de produtos:

1. Simple: Produtos simples, que possuem apenas um preço;
2. Grouped: Produtos sem preço, pois são apenas um agrupamento de outros
   produtos, cada qual com seu preço. Usado quando um produto tem
   várias apresentações;
3. Child: Produtos que fazem parte de um produto
   agrupado. Possuem preço, mas não são exibidos sozinhos. Estes
   produtos só são exibidos dentro dos produtos do tipo Grouped dos
   quais fazem parte.

Uso a tabela children para relacionar a tabela products consigo mesma. Dessa forma, posso relacionar os produtos do tipo Child e Grouped.

Segue o diagrama do banco de dados:

[image: Diagrama do banco de dados]

Os modelos estão relacionados da seguinte forma:

Product belongsTo Type

Product belongsToMany Product

Product hasMany Price

O problema ocorre no momento que tento recuperar o preço dos produtos do tipo Child de um produto do tipo Grouped. Essa informação vem na forma de um Collection do Eloquent, com todos os produtos que fazem parte deste produto agrupado, na ordem de inserção. Gostaria de ordená-los pelo preço, mas o fato desta informação estar em outra tabela dificultou isso. O mais perto que consegui chegar do resultado almejado foi modificando o método do relacionamento entre a classe Product e sí mesma. Segue o código:

```
public function children(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'children', 'father_id', 'child_id')->join('prices', 'child_id', '=', 'product_id')->orderBy('value');
    }
```

No entanto, isso repete alguns valores, já que ele não trás apenas o último preço inserido.

Answer (score 1):

Vê se ajuda:

Como ordernar usando Eloquent: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm

Selecione as 10 primeiras linhas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255508/select-the-first-10-rows-laravel-eloquent
Como pegar o primeiro registro com laravel : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794098/how-to-get-the-first-record-with-laravel-4-raw-queries

Answer (score 0):

Acho que nesse caso seria bacana tu salvar um timestamp até pra você saber quando aquele preço foi colocado e te ajudar na ordenação... coloca um `created_at` na tabela price.
Aproveita e fica a dica de colocar em algumas tabelas ai um campo de criação e outra de modificação até pra tu ter um controle melhor...

Comment: Esses campos não estão no diagrama, mas os criei no migrations do laravel.